# android layout how to set views

Tags: android, xml

In my Android project I want my xml layout as like this picture:--[image]

my code is:--

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#F3F3F3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.12"
            android:id="@+id/la"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_style"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:text="Read it carefully"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"

                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Text view"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Text View"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and,**layout_style.xml** is:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#AEB3B7" />

</shape>
```

Its showing like :--[image]

Where is the problem??or what i have to add here???suggest me please..

Comment: change the width to match_parent of your textview with read it carefully

Comment: I want the layout like the first picture..

Comment: @pramoda ,with the match_parent I am not getting the look like first picture..

Comment: You need two drawables: one white with topLeft & topRight corners rounded. The other grey with bottomLeft & bottomRight corners rounded. Your layout also has redundant views. And a lot of attributes do not belong there.

Comment: @ Vikram, can u give any example(site names) where i can understand it..

Comment: @Vikram, your Suggestion was really great..I got it now..thanks guys for reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should help this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="1">

           <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:text="Read it carefully"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_bg_white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Text view"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:background="@drawable/middle_bg_grey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Text View"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_bg_grey"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

top_rounded_bg_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dip" android:topRightRadius="5dip"/>
               <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
```

middle_bg_grey.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
 </shape>
```

bottom_bg_grey.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip" android:bottomRightRadius="5dip" />

            <solid android:color="@color/grey" />

        </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change textView3 width wrap_content to match_parent and also set transperent background :

**Example :**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent "
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Read it carefully"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1] change width to `match_parent` for textview `read it carefully`

2] add another linear layout and add other two test view in that specify 'layout_weight` to 1 for both so that they can occupy screen space

3] So basically your xml looks like

```
 <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="#F3F3F3">
                <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Read it carefully"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.12">

   // add textviews here
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#F3F3F3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.12"
            android:id="@+id/la"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_style"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="45sp"
            android:text="Read it carefully"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Text view"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Text View"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```